# RAD terminates with Exit code = 160

Tags: rad

Rational Application Developer terminates with Exit code=160. RAD is keep crashing while creating a EAR project. The error message was RAD JVM terminated. Exit code = 160.

Answer (score 4):

In Eclipse.ini file, include the following line.

-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.UseWebKitGTK=true